# How to access the service that I have deployed to Azure K8s?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I have created a 2 node Kubernetes cluster on Azure.

Then I deploy my service using the following yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-st
  labels:
    app: cloud-test
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cloud-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cloud-test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cloud-test
        image: test:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3046
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-st
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: cloud-test
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3046
      targetPort: 3046
```

I am using cluster IP, so I created an ingress for this :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: k8s-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /v1(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
              service:
                name: service-st
                port:
                  number: 3046
```

it seems they are working:
[image]

[image]

i also chekc this box :

[image]

Now, if I access the address of the nginx in services (External Ip), i get 404 from nginx. Also,if i access ip/v1 , get 404 again.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

There your ingress class is mentioned. you are using the **ALB** controller but using the nginx class it's not working.

Nginx **ingress controller** there then you can use **ingressClassName** as **nginx**.

For ref if you refer this article **Nginx** example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli

ALB controller might be using Gateway API, so may not need to create ingress you will be creating resources like deployment i guess. i have not used AKS & it's ingress controller.

read more about **Ingress Vs Gateway** diff :  https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-ingress-vs-gateway-api-647ee233693d

Ref AKS ingress : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-install-existing

Comment: Hi, do you mean I need to turn off the Application Gateway ingress controller in the Networking blade?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to start simple, making sure you access your service when connecting to your virtual host without any rewrite target and when it works build up the rewrite.

(!) Use a host name, not an IP address, for example by configuring your `hosts` file if you do not have a domain registration to use.

For example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service-st
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100mspec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: <your virtual host name>
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-st
                port:
                  number: 3046
```